# How to selectively build using Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, build

We have an app with some service(android service) and aar library that serves as a client. They communicate through AIDL with each other. Our app is for our company use and not published in the Google play for the general public. We would like to build the service only without the aar, each time we push changes and additional features to our app. Is there a way to accomplish this through Gradle, our build system?

Comment: What do you mean by "some service"? Do you mean an Android `Service`? Do you mean a Web service? Do you mean something else?

Comment: Android service. We have server client relationship. I added more clarification now.

Comment: Gradle does not build an individual Java/Kotlin class, usually. Usually, you have it build an app (APK) or a library (AAR). Are you saying that you have an app module, and a library module, and you would like Gradle to only build the app module? If so, run the `assembleRelease` task for that app module.

Comment: The service is a full blown apk and the client is aar library. We would like to build the app each time we add new feature, instead of both the app and library.

Comment: Run the `assembleRelease` task on the app module.